# Strict standards, only variables should be passed PHP error

Tags: php

I get the error "*Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in*" on line 18 and 20.

Line 18:

```
$phpinfo[end(array_keys($phpinfo))][$match[2]] = isset($match[4]) ? array($match[3], $match[4]) : $match[3];
```

Line 20 is : `$phpinfo[end(array_keys($phpinfo))][] = $match[2];`

This is part of an installation script and this is the full php code snippet:

```
<?php  

    ob_start();
    phpinfo(-1);
    $phpinfo = array('phpinfo' => array());
    if(preg_match_all('#(?:<h2>(?:<a name=".*?">)?(.*?)(?:</a>)?</h2>)|(?:<tr(?: class=".*?")?><t[hd](?: class=".*?")?>(.*?)\s*</t[hd]>(?:<t[hd](?: class=".*?")?>(.*?)\s*</t[hd]>(?:<t[hd](?: class=".*?")?>(.*?)\s*</t[hd]>)?)?</tr>)#s', ob_get_clean(), $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
    foreach($matches as $match){
        if(strlen($match[1]))
            $phpinfo[$match[1]] = array();
        elseif(isset($match[3]))
            $phpinfo[end(array_keys($phpinfo))][$match[2]] = isset($match[4]) ? array($match[3], $match[4]) : $match[3];
        else
            $phpinfo[end(array_keys($phpinfo))][] = $match[2];
    }
```

Many thanks for any help you guys can give me.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're passing the result of a function into `end`:

```
$last = end(array_keys($phpinfo));
```

The error appears because `end` not only returns the last item in the array, but moves the internal pointer of the array to the last item, so that (for instance) `current` would subsequently return the last item. For it to be able to do this, `end` takes its argument by reference, but since you are passing it the result of a function, it has no reference to use.

You can assign the result to avoid the error:

```
$keys = array_keys($phpinfo);
$last = end($keys);
```

However, you'd be better storing the value of `$match[1]` and using that:

```
if (strlen($match[1])) {
    $key = $match[1];
    $phpinfo[$key] = array();
} elseif (isset($match[3])) {
    $phpinfo[$key][$match[2]] = isset($match[4]) ? array($match[3], $match[4]) : $match[3];
} else {
    $phpinfo[$key][] = $match[2];
}
```

Comment: aray_pop doesn't solves the problem I still get the strict standards warning. By your logic array_pop also modifies the original array so it should also take its argument by reference

Comment: Thanks for that, not sure what I was thinking there. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`end()` receives a reference to a variable, because it modifies its value.

Your are passing a value. Hence the error:

> only **variables** should be passed **by reference**

You should pass a variable:

```
$keys = array_keys($phpinfo);
$phpinfo[end($keys)];
```